# Android activity won't save information to file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save user information in a single save file in local directory. However every time I run the app, the information doesn't save--I can tell by rerunning the app and the file data isn't updated or returning to the activity and finding out the data displayed isn't updated upon returning to the same activity. Here is the function in the activity where I set up a file output stream and decided to write in the information through a string containing all the User information and display "FILE CLOSED" once I assumed the file has written. Could you spot any missing steps or anything that I missed so that the file can be written?

```
public void saveToFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    //new filestream
    FileOutputStream fostream;
    fostream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Write into file for each User in Array
    for (int i = 0; i < userArrayList.size(); i++){
        String contents = userArrayList.get(i).display();
        System.out.println(userArrayList.get(i).display());
        try {
            fostream.write(contents.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("NOTHING WRITTEN");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        fostream.close();
        System.out.println("FILE CLOSED");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: 1. You can always refer stacktrace for your error if applicable. 
2. Have you included permission for writing to external storage?

Comment: Do I need to add those permissions for just writing into local directory? Also, what should I find in the stacktrace to find the issue?